# VBA - getting name of the label in mousemove event

Tags: excel, vba, events, label, mousemove

I have following problem. I have a lot of labels in my worksheet named in a structured way (Label1, Label2, ..., Label9) and mousemove-event macros assigned to all of them. I want to get ith value in table A1:A9, where "i" is a number of label, which is currently "touched". Is there a simple way to get label's name during mouse_move event (or some other events like Change_event). It would be look simmilar to this

```
Private Sub Label47_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer,
                              ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

Dim label_name as String
Dim which_one as Integer
Dim val as Integer

label_name = "something like ActiveLabel.Name"
which_one = CInt(right(label_name,1))
val = Cells(which_one,1).Value

                rest code....

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Don't you already know which label it is, since you are writing code in that controls `MouseMove` event handler? (In the example above, `label_name` = "Label47")

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class module and `WithEvents` to do what you need.  The following code should get you going in the right direction:

```
'weMouseMove class module:
Private WithEvents mLbl As MSForms.Label
Private mLabelColl As Collection

Sub LabelsToTrack(Labels As Variant)
    Set mLabelColl = New Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(Labels) To UBound(Labels)
        Dim LblToTrack As weMouseMove
        Set LblToTrack = New weMouseMove

        Dim Lbl As MSForms.Label
        Set Lbl = Labels(i)

        LblToTrack.TrackLabel Lbl
        mLabelColl.Add LblToTrack
    Next i
End Sub

Sub TrackLabel(Lbl As MSForms.Label)
    Set mLbl = Lbl
End Sub

Private Sub mLbl_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
                           ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    MsgBox mLbl.Name & ": " & mLbl.Caption
End Sub
```

And in your userform code module:

```
Dim MouseMove As New weMouseMove

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    MouseMove.LabelsToTrack Array(Me.Label1, Me.Label2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit greenhorn in using class modules, that's why I kindly ask for clarification.

Comment: This is a working sample.  Create a new class module named weMouseMove and paste the code from the first sample into that class module.  Then paste the code from the second sample into the form that contains the labels you want to process.  You will need to change the contents of the array from `Me.Label0, Me.Label1, Me.Label3` to use the labels from your form.  Then put a breakpoint on the MouseMove.LabelsToTrack line in the form open code, open the form, and step through the code.  If you have specific implementation questions, it would be best to ask those as separate questions.

Comment: Sorry for that poor comment - I was editing the post. I appreciate your help. My questions are: 1. My labels are located in the worksheet not in the form - how can I create an instance? 2. Could you explain the use of this Collection? I quite don't understand the whole process when I touch one of the labels and how the mLbl_MouseMove event with msgbox is triggered. Thank you in advance.

Comment: One thing to add. I followed your instructions and I got an error: "Object does not source automatic events". Here is the file http://www.speedyshare.com/7rHjt/example.xlsm

Comment: I was mistakenly thinking that you wanted to do this in MS Access.  I've updated my answer to provide Excel-friendly code instead.