# Is it possible to highlight a range when a user hovers over a custom button/ribbon control on Excel ribbon

Tags: xml, vba, excel, ribbon-control

I knows it's possible to temporarily highlight a cell or range of cells when a user hovers over them directly (as shown [here](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/168376-code-to-highlight-Excel-row-upon-hover) and [here](http://optionexplicitvba.blogspot.com/2011/04/rollover-b8-ov1.html?m=1)). But, is it possible to highlight a cell or range of cells when a user hovers over a custom button/ribbon control on the Excel ribbon?

**Some context**

I have a custom tab with buttons/ribbon controls that run macros included in my add-in when clicked. I created the additional tab using Microsoft's Custom RibbonUI program, coding in xml. I'd like to highlight a range (let's say column A) to show a user where they should put their data before running that particular macro that that button calls. I guess it would basically be doing this in place of showing the tooltip/supertip? I'd prefer if it could do both, show the tip and highlight the cells, but if it's only possible in place of the tooltip that's ok.

1. Is this even possible?

   - Even if there's a huge workaround I'm open to hear it.
2. If it's not possible, what would you suggest I do in place of it to **show** the user where to put their data?

Could using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22485372/2962937) that uses the `MouseMove` Event work? Can that event be applied to an `IRibbonControl`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a hover option, but that would be cool if you could figure that out.  A workaround that may work for your scenario is to highlight the cell/range, use `Application.Wait` to pause for *x* amount of seconds, then un-highlight the cell/range.

The below code does this with Column A.  Highlights it yellow, waits 1.5 seconds, then un-highlights.

```
Sub test1()

newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + 1.5
waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)

With Columns("A:A").Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Application.Wait waitTime
With Columns("A:A").Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is an interesting workaround. But, how would this be implemented? Where would this be called from? Unfortunately, I need a way to call something on the fly :/

Comment: could be an additional button within your worksheet of other macros.  One that could be associated with the task at hand, with a label like "Entry Location" or something