# Access VBA listing collection items in a class module

Tags: vba, class, ms-access, collections

Although I'm reasonable experienced VBA developer, I have not had the need to use class modules or collections but thought this may be my opportunity to extend my knowledge.

In an application I have a number of forms which all have the same functionality and I now need to increase that functionality. Towards that, I am trying to reorder a collection in a class module, but get an error 91 - object variable or with block not set. The collection is created when I assign events to controls. The original code I obtained from here (Many thanks mwolfe) [VBA - getting name of the label in mousemove event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484792/vba-getting-name-of-the-label-in-mousemove-event)

and has been adapted to Access. The assignments of events works well and all the events work *providing I am only doing something with that control* such as change a background color, change size or location on the form.

The problem comes when I want to reorder it in the collection - with a view to having an impact on location in the form. However I am unable to access the collection itself in the first place.

The below is my latest attempt and the error occurs in the collcount Get indicated by asterisks (right at the bottom of the code block). I am using Count as a test. Once I understand what I am doing wrong I should be able to manipulate it as required.

mLabelColl returns a correct count before leaving the LabelsToTrack function, but is then not found in any other function.

As you will see from the commented out debug statements, I have tried making mLabelColl Private and Dim in the top declaration, using 'Debug.Print mLabelColl.Count' in the mousedown event and trying to create a different class to store the list of labels.

I feel I am missing something pretty simple but I'm at a loss as to what - can someone please put me out of my misery

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'weMouseMove class module:
Private WithEvents mLbl As Access.Label
Public mLabelColl As Collection
'Dim LblList as clLabels

Function LabelsToTrack(ParamArray labels() As Variant)
Set mLabelColl = New Collection 'assign a pointer
Dim i As Integer

    For i = LBound(labels) To UBound(labels)

        'Set mLabelColl = New Collection events not assigned if set here
        Dim LblToTrack As weMouseMove 'needs to be declared here - why?
        Set LblToTrack = New weMouseMove 'assign a pointer

        Dim lbl As Access.Label
        Set lbl = labels(i)

        LblToTrack.TrackLabel lbl
        mLabelColl.Add LblToTrack 'add to mlabelcoll collection

        'Set LblList as New clLabels
        'LblList.addLabel lbl

    Next i
    Debug.Print mLabelColl.Count 'returns correct number
    Debug.Print dsform.countcoll '1 - incorrect

End Function

Sub TrackLabel(lbl As Access.Label)

    Set mLbl = lbl

End Sub

Private Sub mLbl_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, Y As Single)
Dim tLbl As Access.Label

    'Debug.Print LblList.Count 'Compile error - Expected function or variable (Despite Count being an option
    'Debug.Print mLabelColl.Count 'error 91
    'Debug.Print LblList.CountLbls 'error 91
    Debug.Print collCount

End Sub

Property Get collCount() As Integer

    *collCount = mLabelColl.Count* 'error 91

End Property
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "having an impact on location in the form". The code above doesn't have anything to do with control positioning - that's in the control properties themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have all the `weMouseMove` objects reference the same collection in their `mLabelColl` pointer, a single line can achieve it:

```
LblToTrack.TrackLabel lbl
mLabelColl.Add LblToTrack
Set LblToTrack.mLabelColl = mLabelColl ' <-- Add this line.
```

But please be aware that this leads to a circular reference between the collection and its contained objects, a problem that is known to be a source of memory leaks, but this should not be an important issue in this case.

Comment: Many thanks for responses.@Comintern. The example is just a test

Comment: @CJ_London I would like to know if this solves the current issue (the access to the collection and the count). Please provide feedback when you can, thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for responses.@Comintern. The example is just a test. Once I can access the collection, I can reference the collection. So for example, the click event might be used to update an internal tab order, or reposition other controls. @A.S.H, unfortunately adding the line generates another err 91. I tried changing to LblToTrack.mLabelColl.Add mLabelColl, but get the same err. I'm trying to understand how collections are created and feel I'm thrashing about trying this and that to see what works without really understanding why. I'm very familiar with using Form collections.

Comment: Sorry A.S.H - hit the wrong button before I had finished the comment!

Comment: Ah, sorry! `Set` was missing, please retry with the Edit.

Comment: @ A.S.H. That did the trick - Many Thanks! Can you recommend any good reading/sites on collections. I like to annotate my code with what it is doing and why and whilst trying to learn something new, put in lots of explanations  - the act of doing so also helps fix it in my brain! Also concerned about your comment re memory leaks - please can you elaborate. Many thanks again

Comment: @CJ_London Great, it is good to make a further step in your interesting project. The issue that happened here with the collection is not specific to it, but to OOP in general, and the way VB implements the concept. Therefore I dont have any specific book to recommend (been in the practice for many years) but there are plenty on the subject. Next comment I will elaborate on the issue.

Comment: When you define the class `weMouseMove`, you declared in it a "pointer" called mLabelColl. It means that every instance of this class will  hold a reference on some Collection. The pointer point nowhere yet, until the time you *create* the collection and direct the pointer to it (`Set mLabelColl = New Collection`). Next comes the problem that we want all *instances* of  `weMouseMove` (created with `new`) have their pointers set to the same collection, hence the fix we made.

Comment: Got it thanks. Tried to mark your answer as 'The' answer, but not sure if I've done it right. Seem to have got a -1 against my original post and a tick against your answer - is that what it is supposed to look like?

Comment: The problem of circular references is a trademark of VBA (VB6) because the *garbage collector* (a thread that frees the memory allocated by *killing* objects that die / go out of scope), takes its decision on the basis that an object has no longer any pointer toward it. Problem is, when two objects have pointers to each other, the GC will never decide to kill them, hence the "memory leak:" they remain alive even though both are not needed any more. hope this makes things a bit clearer :)